# I want to make any column of my table unique in dexie js indexdb

Tags: javascript

e.preventDefault();
values = {
primery_key: 0,
name: $('#name').val(),
type: $('#type').val(),
cnic: $('#cnic').val(),
address: $('#address').val(),
mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
email: $('#email').val(),
ptcl_number: $('#ptcl_number').val(),
broker_pic: $('#broker_pic').val(),
};

```
        if(values.name == '' || values.type == '' || values.cnic == '' || values.address == '' || values.mobile == '' || values.email == '' || values.ptcl_number == '' || values.broker_pic == '')
        {
            toastr.error('Please fill all the fields');
        }
        else
        {
            tempdb_conn.broker_table.add(values).unique(['primery_key']).then(function(id) {
                toastr.success('Data saved successfully.');
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#type').val('');
                $('#cnic').val('');
                $('#address').val('');
                $('#mobile').val('');
                $('#email').val('');
                $('#ptcl_number').val('');
                $('#broker_pic').val('');
            }).catch(function(e) {
                toastr.error('Data already exist.');
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Dixie.js, but checking the documentation I'm guessing something like this...
In your collection every column you want to be unique needs to be a primary key.

See schema Schema Syntax at https://dexie.org/docs/Version/Version.stores()

Then use uniqueKeys()
https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.uniqueKeys()

Like this:

```
tempdb_conn.broker_table.add(values).uniqueKeys(function() {
    toastr.success('Data saved successfully.');
    $('#name').val('');
    $('#type').val('');
    $('#cnic').val('');
    $('#address').val('');
    $('#mobile').val('');
    $('#email').val('');
    $('#ptcl_number').val('');
    $('#broker_pic').val('');
}).catch(function(e) {
    toastr.error('Data already exist.');
});
```